# How to add unix timestamp as expiry in Redis records?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I am trying to add a unix timestamp to a record in redis so I am using `expireat` to do so. I have been able to achieve what I want using the following:

```
tokenBlacklist.set(splitId[0], splitId[1]);
tokenBlacklist.expireat(splitId[0], tokenExp); //tokenExp example: 1558786197
```

Now, I want to know if there is any one liner to the above solution, something like:

```
tokenBlacklist.set(splitId[0], splitId[1], "EX", tokenExp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET` command can only specify a TTL, NOT an expiration time point. So you can use the `tokenExp - current-time-in-second` as the argument.

```
tokenBlacklist.set(splitId[0], splitId[1], "EX", tokenExp - Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));
```

**NOTE:**

I'm not familiar with javascript. If the way to get current Unix time in second in wrong, please point it out. Thanks.

Comment: the javascript way is correct and it is definitely a way to do in one line. It works. But is there any other command for `expireat` that can be used?

Comment: NO. AFAIK, there's no such built-in command. Of course, you can write a Lua script to do the job. But that should be more complicated.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. I did as in your answer but with momentJs